# How to use worker threads in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, node-worker-threads

I have below code, Where passing array length is too high and processing each array element taking one second of time, How i can use worker threads in below condition?

```
function processData(arr){
    var result = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        result.push(process(arr[i]));
    }
    return result;
}

function process() {
    // some code here takes 1 second to execute
}

processData(arr);
```

Comment: You can use `workerpool` npm package for the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use `workerpool` npm package to do your long processing job in a worker thread, something like this

```
const workerpool = require('workerpool');

const pool =  workerpool.pool();

const arr = [...] // Large Data set which is to be processed

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  pool.exec(
    arr => {
      var result = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        /* 
        Do the long processing on data 
        */
        const processedData = a[i];
        result.push(processedData);
      }
      return result;
    },
    [arr]
  )
  .then(result => resolve(result))
  .catch(err => reject(err));
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Aayush, How to handle scenario that in function process() , i call functions from other files, Ex const util = require('./utils');  so how do i access "util.calculate()" in pool.exec()

Comment: The data you send to the workers is sent in the serialized form, hence you can send references to the functions and objects, but the function inside the workerpool will not communicate to the outer world objects. Check here
https://www.npmjs.com/package/workerpool#offload-functions-dynamically

Comment: So its difficult for me to add everything in single function process() in order to meet this criteria. is there another way to handle this?